# jQuery on click function To li and nested li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function that basically closes the slide on menu on click then goes to the url so it looks nicer. Works great on the parent set of `li` tags but nested ones it doesnt. Looks like `href` gets returned as the nested `li` clicked and the parent one so it fails.

#### jQuery code:

```
$('#menu-pages li').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /* Act on the event */
  var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
  page.toggleClass('menu-open');
  mobileMenu.toggleClass('mobile-menu-open');

  page.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    window.location = href;
  });
});
```

#### HTML code:

```
<div id="menu-pages">
  <li><a href="/dashboard/">My Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="/Community/">Community</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/forum/">forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="/messages/">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="/groups/">groups</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/teachings/">Teachings</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/teachings/?category=Creativity">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="/teachings/?category=Craft">Craft</a></li>
      <li><a href="/teachings/?category=Coaching">Coaching</a></li>
      <li><a href="/teachings/?category=Conversations">Conversations</a></li>
      <li><a href="/checklists/">Checklists</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have nested li tags and the click event is probably triggering from the outer tag before the inner tag.

You could always change it to the "a" tag and also use a delegate for a single even listener

The delegate approach may also fix the "li" tag click event order as it will bubble up from the child element

```
 $('#menu-pages').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

         event.preventDefault();
         /* Act on the event */
         var href = $(this).attr('href');

         page.toggleClass('menu-open');
         mobileMenu.toggleClass('mobile-menu-open');

         page.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
              window.location = href;
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` before the `event.preventDefault()` to stop the event from bubbling.

This way, if you click the inner `li` it will not perform that action and then the parent `li`.

---

For more information consider the following resources:

- [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)